# How to disable JS function via CSS for certain page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a JS which is applied globally to return a pop-up alert message when a user tries to link outside of the site:

```
$("a[target='_blank']").click( function() {
    return confirm('Please don’t leave...');
});
```

Is there a simple CSS script that I could apply to certain pages to ignore this global function on a page by page (or div class by div class) basis?

Comment: You shouldn't annoy users with such alerts ;-)

Comment: *"Is there a simple CSS script that I could apply to certain pages to ignore this global function"* No, there isn't.

Comment: Look at [CSS pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: @Givi unfortunately only supported in IE11. If only IE would crawl away somewhere and die. I would also argue that CSS has no place in governing what UI elements can and cannot be interacted with.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `pointer-events: none;` is cross-browser [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/KMJnA/10/), or at least working on latest version of all major browsers.

Comment: @Givi depending on who you believe, IE10 and older covers around 30% of all web users. You cannot have functionality that doesn't work for that many people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS is for styling, and will not help in this situation. However you can add a `class` to the elements you want to ignore this function on, and add the `not()` method. Try this:

```
$("a[target='_blank']").not('.allow-click').click( function() {
    return confirm('Please don’t leave...');
});
```

Note you will need to add the `allow-click` class, like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank" class="allow-click">Foo</a>
```

Also note, that popping up an alert before someone leaves your site is ***really*** annoying, and generally considered a bad thing to be doing.

Comment: @Presto There are better ways of doing it, such as upon clicking an external link going to an intermediary page where the user can click the link again to be sent to the page. Still annoying, but at least it's not an ugly confirm dialog.